# How to tell if a FreeBSD host needs a reboot to activate the new kernel?

Tags: freebsd

"uname" will tell me the version of the running kernel. How do I know if this is different from the installed kernel (i.e. the one that will be loaded on the next reboot)?

Ideally I'd like to write a script that can output "reboot needed" or "running and installed kernel match".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `freebsd-version -k`! From its [manual](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=freebsd-version&sektion=1):

> -k          Print the version and patch level of the installed
>   kernel.
>                    Unlike uname(1), if a new kernel has been installed but the
>                    system has not yet rebooted, freebsd-version will print the
>                    version and patch level of the new kernel.

You should compare output of `freebsd-version -k` and `uname -r` and if differs you should `reboot`.

Another option is to use `strings` (idea taken from `/bin/freebsd-version`):

```
strings /boot/kernel/kernel | sed -n "s,^@(#)FreeBSD \([^ ]*\).*,\1,p"
```

Comment: `freebsd-version -k` shows only release name and patch level. It works for binary updates, but if system updated from source it is not enough. E. g. you can update OS several times, but `freebsd-version -k` will show the same value 11.0-STABLE

Answer (score 0):

Simple, but probably not reliable way: compare boot time (from `sysctl kern.boottime`) and time when kernel was installed (`stat -f '%c' $(sysctl -n kern.bootfile)`). Time should be always synced (via ntp) for this method to work.

Better way is to compare version strings from running kernel and installed kernel file.

From running kernel it can be obtained via `sysctl -n kern.version | head -1` (this string is also shown in uname -v but in one line instead two lines). Then you can `fgrep` this string in the kernel file (`kern.bootfile`) - if it found - running and installed kernel version should match. I don't like using grep here, but it should work good enough. More correct way of extracting version string from kernel file would be some program to extract `version` variable from kernel ELF data (e. g. using libelf).